# Song track info of Google Play Music App

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I want song title, artist and album name of song playing on Google play music.

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
        String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        songName.setText(track);
        artistName.setText(artist);
        albumName.setText(album);
    }
};

private void registerSongTrackReceiver() {
    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();

    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");  
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
}
```

I am using above code. I have register this receiver for retrieving song title. It gives default stock music player title when I am using Google play Music.

Comment: Can you show more code ? Your entire Activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got the solution using RemoteController class.Now I get the track info of every music player.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html

Here is the example for implementation

https://github.com/DrBreen/RemoteControllerExample/tree/master/src/com/woodblockwithoutco/remotecontrollerexample

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution for older APIs, as NotificationListenerService was introduced in Lollipop?

Comment: Not for Older api. For older version below KITKAT you need to use broadcast receiver as mention in question but its not working with all music player. For Kitkat you can use RemoteController class and for LOLLIPOP use MediaController class because RemoteController is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the info. As around 50% of devices still run below KitKat (API < 19), I guess I'll skip this for all APIs to maintain consistency across all APIs.